# Generating primary key values after new column has been added to Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I have a table with 2 varchar2 columns. I have added new number column to existing table to make this column primary key. This table now includes 3 columns. I gave a try to use anonymous block as following:



`declare

cnt number;

begin

select nvl(count(*),0) into cnt from sometable;

for i in 1..cnt

loop

update sometable set id=i where i=rownum;

end loop;

end;`


Using this anonymous block updates this table unexpectedly.
My solution was to use the following statement:

`create table sometablecopy as select row_number() over(order by sometable.col1) as id, sometable.* from sometable;`
Nevertheless I am curios why doesn't anonymous block produce expected primary key values with the help of rownum pseudocolumn? It must be rownum related issue.

Comment: What was the unexpected result?

Comment: Rownum is assigned when a result is returned. As a consequence you can never do a `SELECT ... WHERE rownum < 1` because if there is at least one row, then the first one MUST have rownum equal to 1.

Comment: StevieG: all row have the same primary key values except the first row. First row has number 1 and other rows have cnt variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rownum is a pseudocolumn.  Its assigned to rows as they are returned from the select.  So you can't say "select * from my_table where rownum = 42" since the row with rownum=42 hasn't been defined yet, it will vary depending on your select and predicate (and "select * from my_table where rownum = 1" will return a single row, not the "first" row, whatever that would be).  You could do something like (untested):

```
declare
  cursor sel_cur is
  select rowid as row_id
  from my_table
  order by orderby_col;

  v_ctr pls_integer := 0;
begin
  for rec in sel_cur
  loop
    v_ctr := v_ctr + 1;
    update my_table set pk_col = v_ctr where rowid = rec.row_id;
  end loop;
  commit;
exception
  when others then 
  rollback;
  raise;
end;
```

This assumes you have sufficient rollback to update the entire table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works great and I will use it! Thanks!

Comment: Peter Lang suggest very simple solution instead of this. When UPDATE statement needs to be more complicated then using cursor and rowid is more efficent way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `ROWNUM` like that (see [ROWNUM in SQL](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/rownum.html)).

What you could have done is this:

```
UPDATE sometable SET id = ROWNUM;
```

Comment: Actually it is too simple to make up but for the purpose of this task it's acceptable :)

Comment: @reforrer: Not sure what you mean. How can anything be too simple?